# Difference of implementation of neural network bias

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have learned 3 different implementation of neural network with bias neurons, but I searched little literatures to illustrate the difference between them. Suppose we have `X=[x1,x2]`

1. Add additional dimension to input data. [Ref](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/)

```py
Xdata = np.array([[x1,x2,1]]).T
Z1 = np.dot(W1, A0)
A1 = relu(Z1)
Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1)
```

bias update is not considered.

Detail are follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

@author         yaoyaoyao
@date             Sun Oct 20 19:03:21 2019
@version        V1.0


"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

def f(x1,x2):
    return x1**2+5*x2+1

X1 = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
X2 = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
Ydata = f(X1,X2)


Xdata = np.hstack((X1[:,np.newaxis],X2[:,np.newaxis]))
Ydata = Ydata[:, np.newaxis]


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


def sigmoid_backward(x):
    y = sigmoid(x)
    return y * (1 - y)


def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)


def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)


def tanh_backward(x):
    return 1 - np.tanh(x) ** 2


def relu_backward(x):
    xcp = np.ones(x.shape)
    xcp[x <= 0] = 0
    return xcp


data_size = Xdata.shape[0]
all_index = np.arange(data_size)
train = np.random.choice(all_index, np.int(data_size * 0.9))
test = np.setdiff1d(all_index, train)
X = np.array(Xdata)
y = np.array(Ydata)

Xtrain = X[train]
Xtest = X[test]
ytrain = y[train]
ytest = y[test]

eps = 0.001
h = 20
W1 = np.random.randn(h, 2) * eps
b1 = np.random.randn(h, 1) * eps
W2 = np.random.randn(1, h) * eps
b2 = np.random.randn(1, 1) * eps

m = Xtrain.shape[0]

beta1 = 0.9  
beta2 = 0.999  
epsilon = 0.00000001

adam_optimizer = {
    'm_W1': np.zeros(W1.shape),
    'v_W1': np.zeros(W1.shape),
    'm_b1': np.zeros(b1.shape),
    'v_b1': np.zeros(b1.shape),

    'm_W2': np.zeros(W2.shape),
    'v_W2': np.zeros(W2.shape),
    'm_b2': np.zeros(b2.shape),
    'v_b2': np.zeros(b2.shape)}

learning_rate = 0.01

reg_lambda = 10
for j in range(10000):
    A0 = Xtrain.T
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, A0) + b1
    A1 = relu(Z1)

    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = Z2

    ytraint = ytrain.reshape(A2.shape)
    if j % 100 == 0:
        print('loss:', np.sqrt(np.sum(ytraint - A2) ** 2 / m))

    error = - (ytraint - A2)

    dZ2 = error
    dW2 = np.dot(dZ2, A1.T) / m + W2 * reg_lambda / m
    db2 = np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m

    dA1 = np.dot(W2.T, dZ2)
    dZ1 = dA1 * relu_backward(Z1)
    dW1 = np.dot(dZ1, A0.T) / m + W1 * reg_lambda / m
    db1 = np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m

    t = j + 1
    adam_optimizer['m_W1'] = beta1 * adam_optimizer['m_W1'] + (1 - beta1) * dW1
    adam_optimizer['v_W1'] = beta2 * adam_optimizer['v_W1'] + (1 - beta2) * dW1 ** 2
    m_w_corrected = adam_optimizer['m_W1'] / (1 - beta1 ** t)
    v_w_corrected = adam_optimizer['v_W1'] / (1 - beta2 ** t)

    # for b
    adam_optimizer['m_b1'] = beta1 * adam_optimizer['m_b1'] + (1 - beta1) * db1
    adam_optimizer['v_b1'] = beta2 * adam_optimizer['v_b1'] + (1 - beta2) * db1 ** 2
    m_b_corrected = adam_optimizer['m_b1'] / (1 - beta1 ** t)
    v_b_corrected = adam_optimizer['v_b1'] / (1 - beta2 ** t)

    W1 -= learning_rate * m_w_corrected / (np.sqrt(v_w_corrected) + epsilon)
    b1 -= learning_rate * m_b_corrected / (np.sqrt(v_b_corrected) + epsilon)

    adam_optimizer['m_W2'] = beta1 * adam_optimizer['m_W2'] + (1 - beta1) * dW2
    adam_optimizer['v_W2'] = beta2 * adam_optimizer['v_W2'] + (1 - beta2) * dW2 ** 2
    m_w_corrected = adam_optimizer['m_W2'] / (1 - beta1 ** t)
    v_w_corrected = adam_optimizer['v_W2'] / (1 - beta2 ** t)

    # for b
    adam_optimizer['m_b2'] = beta1 * adam_optimizer['m_b2'] + (1 - beta1) * db2
    adam_optimizer['v_b2'] = beta2 * adam_optimizer['v_b2'] + (1 - beta2) * db2 ** 2
    m_b_corrected = adam_optimizer['m_b2'] / (1 - beta1 ** t)
    v_b_corrected = adam_optimizer['v_b2'] / (1 - beta2 ** t)

    W2 -= learning_rate * m_w_corrected / (np.sqrt(v_w_corrected) + epsilon)
    b2 -= learning_rate * m_b_corrected / (np.sqrt(v_b_corrected) + epsilon)


def nnforward(X):
    A0 = X.T
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, A0) + b1
    A1 = relu(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = Z2
    return A2


A2 = nnforward(Xtest)
ytestt = ytest.reshape(A2.shape)
print('test loss:', np.sum(ytestt - A2) ** 2 / m)
```

2. Add bias to the sum of activation with updating it during back propagation process. This is what we learn from course.

```py
# forawrd propagation
# general, b1 and b2 are a constant
Xdata = np.array([[x1,x2]]).T
Z1 = np.dot(W1, A0) + b1
A1 = relu(Z1)
Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2

# back propagation

db2 = ...

db1 = ...

b2+=db2

b1+=db1
```

Detail

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

@author         yaoyaoyao
@date             Sun Oct 20 19:03:21 2019
@version        V1.0


"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)


def f(x1,x2):
    return x1**2+5*x2+1

K=10
X1 = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)*K
X2 = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)*K
Ydata = f(X1,X2)


Xdata = np.hstack((X1[:,np.newaxis],X2[:,np.newaxis],np.ones((Ydata.shape[0],1))))
Ydata = Ydata[:, np.newaxis]


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


def sigmoid_backward(x):
    y = sigmoid(x)
    return y * (1 - y)


def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)


def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)


def tanh_backward(x):
    return 1 - np.tanh(x) ** 2


def relu_backward(x):
    xcp = np.ones(x.shape)
    xcp[x <= 0] = 0.
    return xcp


data_size = Xdata.shape[0]
all_index = np.arange(data_size)
train = np.random.choice(all_index, np.int(data_size * 0.9))
test = np.setdiff1d(all_index, train)
X = np.array(Xdata)
y = np.array(Ydata)

Xtrain = X[train]
Xtest = X[test]
ytrain = y[train]
ytest = y[test]

eps = 0.001
h = 30
W1 = np.random.randn(h, 3) * eps
W2 = np.random.randn(1, h) * eps

m = Xtrain.shape[0]

beta1 = 0.9  
beta2 = 0.999  
epsilon = 0.00000001  

adam_optimizer = {
    'm_W1': np.zeros(W1.shape),
    'v_W1': np.zeros(W1.shape),

    'm_W2': np.zeros(W2.shape),
    'v_W2': np.zeros(W2.shape),
}

learning_rate = 0.01

reg_lambda = 10
for j in range(10000):
    A0 = Xtrain.T
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, A0)
    A1 = relu(Z1)

    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1)
    A2 = Z2

    ytraint = ytrain.reshape(A2.shape)
    if j % 100 == 0:
        print('loss:', np.sqrt(np.sum(ytraint - A2) ** 2 / m))


    error = - (ytraint - A2)

    dZ2 = error
    dW2 = np.dot(dZ2, A1.T) / m + W2 * reg_lambda / m

    dA1 = np.dot(W2.T, dZ2)
    dZ1 = dA1 * relu_backward(Z1)
    dW1 = np.dot(dZ1, A0.T) / m + W1 * reg_lambda / m

    t = j + 1

    adam_optimizer['m_W2'] = beta1 * adam_optimizer['m_W2'] + (1 - beta1) * dW2
    adam_optimizer['v_W2'] = beta2 * adam_optimizer['v_W2'] + (1 - beta2) * dW2 ** 2
    m_w_corrected = adam_optimizer['m_W2'] / (1 - beta1 ** t)
    v_w_corrected = adam_optimizer['v_W2'] / (1 - beta2 ** t)

    W2 -= learning_rate * m_w_corrected / (np.sqrt(v_w_corrected) + epsilon)

    adam_optimizer['m_W1'] = beta1 * adam_optimizer['m_W1'] + (1 - beta1) * dW1
    adam_optimizer['v_W1'] = beta2 * adam_optimizer['v_W1'] + (1 - beta2) * dW1 ** 2
    m_w_corrected = adam_optimizer['m_W1'] / (1 - beta1 ** t)
    v_w_corrected = adam_optimizer['v_W1'] / (1 - beta2 ** t)

    W1 -= learning_rate * m_w_corrected / (np.sqrt(v_w_corrected) + epsilon)


def nnforward(X):
    A0 = X.T
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, A0)
    A1 = relu(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1)
    A2 = Z2
    return A2


A2 = nnforward(Xtest)
ytestt = ytest.reshape(A2.shape)
print('test loss:', np.sum(ytestt - A2) ** 2 / m)
```

so what's the difference? I have implemented both, but I found that, if I changed K in demo of method 2, loss would not converge to the minimum. The max K turns out to be 6.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the same. Let's see an example. Let `W=[w11,w12;w21,w22]`, `b=[b1;b2]` and `x=[x1;x2]`. Then from 1 (`W'=[w11,w12,b1;w21,w22,b2]` a 2x3 matrix and `x=[x1;x2;1]`) it follows that `W'*x'=[w11,w12,b1;w21,w22,b2]*[x1;x2;1]=[w11*x1+w12*x2+b1*1;w21*x1+w22*x2+b2*1]=[w11*x1+w12*x2;w21*x1+w22]+[b1*1;b2*1]=W*x+b`, which is equal to 2.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my questions and pasted my codes. Could you please try them? I'm confused about the result, it seems that method 1 has some restrictions.